# XSL 1.0 Transformation to merge Nodes

Tags: xslt

Is it possble to do the transformation below using XSL 1.0. If yes can please post some sample code which can get me started in the right direction.

```
<Region> 
<RecType1><Amt> 100 </Amt></RecType1><RecType2><Name>XXX</Name></RecType2><RecType1><Amt> 200 </Amt></RecType1><RecType2><Name>YYY</Name></RecType2><RecType1><Amt> 300 </Amt></RecType1><RecType2><Name>ZZZ</Name></RecType2></Region>
```

TO

```
<Region> 
<Payment><Amt>100</Amt><Name>XXX</Name></Payment><Payment><Amt>200</Amt><Name>YYY</Name></Payment><Payment><Amt>300</Amt><Name>ZZZ</Name></Payment></Region>
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="RecType1">
   <Payment>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | following-sibling::RecType2[1]/*"/>
   </Payment>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="RecType2"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (indented to be made readable):

```
<Region>
    <RecType1>
        <Amt> 100 </Amt>
    </RecType1>
    <RecType2>
        <Name>XXX</Name>
    </RecType2>
    <RecType1>
        <Amt> 200 </Amt>
    </RecType1>
    <RecType2>
        <Name>YYY</Name>
    </RecType2>
    <RecType1>
        <Amt> 300 </Amt>
    </RecType1>
    <RecType2>
        <Name>ZZZ</Name>
    </RecType2>
</Region>
```

**produces the desired result** (also indented to be readable):

```
<Region>
    <Payment>
        <Amt> 100 </Amt>
        <Name>XXX</Name>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <Amt> 200 </Amt>
        <Name>YYY</Name>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <Amt> 300 </Amt>
        <Name>ZZZ</Name>
    </Payment>
</Region>
```